# Gammu SMS in Arabic using PHP does not be delivered

Tags: php, linux, sms, arabic, gammu

I'm trying to have my own SMS gateway on my server using PHP. I have installed Gammu and I configured the permissions and settings well. Now  it send SMS fine using the following prototype script:

```
<?php
$text = $_POST['text'];
$numb = $_POST['numb'];
if ($text != '' && $numb != ''){
  //die('echo "'.$text.'" | gammu --sendsms TEXT '.$numb);
  echo "<pre>";
  //die(passthru('whoami'));
  $command = 'echo "'.$text.'" | gammu --sendsms TEXT '.$numb.' >> '.__DIR__.'/smslog.txt';//.'" | gammu --sendsms TEXT '.$numb;

  echo passthru($command);
  //echo $command;
}
else{
  ?>
  <form method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="numb">
  <textarea name="text"></textarea>
  <input type="submit">
  </form>
  <?php
}
?>
```

However, everything works fine with English text (Latin) SMS, but trying to send Arabic SMS failed to be delivered to the destination in spite of carrier respond with OK,

```
Sending SMS 1/1....waiting for network answer..OK, message reference=18
```

Also, I noticed that, from terminal, using the same gammu command with Arabic text, it delivered well, but with `?? ??????? ???` text representation. I am, partially, believe that it is encoding issue, but I have no idea how to solve it.

My server is Ubuntu Linux 16.04.

#### Update:

I have figured out how to send Arabic text from the bash using gammu command like the following in which `-unicode` option is used:

```
gammu sendsms TEXT 022222222 -unicode -text "نص عربي"
```

> **However**, the script regarded above, send the Arabic message but it look something like `333333333` on the phone. I have no any idea about what
>   occurred to the string when it send to the command stream via
>   `passthru` and I tried to use `exec` also and the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after many reading of [this section of documentation](https://wammu.eu/docs/manual/gammu/#cmdoption-gammu-textutf8) and many tries, I have found the correct command's options to be like the following:

```
gammu -c /etc/gammurc sendsms  TEXT 02222000 -unicode -textutf8 "نص عربي"
```

In the above example `-textutf8` is used instead of `-text`. Also, notice that `-c` configurations file path is supplied optionally to just make sure what device is going to be used.