# gammu not sending special characters via PHP commandline

Tags: php, laravel, sms, raspberry-pi3, gammu

I'm trying to send and SMS string over a PHP laravel controller on a raspberry 2 (Raspian Linux) and i have the following function for that:

```
 public function processCmd($smsmodel) {

        $smsnumbertmp=str_replace(' ', '', $smsmodel->smsnumber);
        echo 'sudo gammu-smsd-inject TEXT ' .  $smsnumbertmp . " -unicode -text " . $smsmodel->smstext;

        exec("sudo gammu-smsd-inject TEXT " .  $smsnumbertmp . " -unicode -text " . $smsmodel->smstext);

     return "success";
    }
```

The result on the commandline is the following:

```
Actual Timestamp 2019-06-27 06:33:20sudo gammu-smsd-inject TEXT +436802472618 -unicode -text öäüüüüü
```

I've a SMS.sh script which calls the Service every 10 sec and checks if there is anything in the outbox to send.

If i use this string directly in the console 
sudo gammu-smsd-inject TEXT +436802472618 -unicode -text öäüüüüü
it works fine - i get the sms with the special characters

if i use the exact same string with the exec() command from the PHP controller i get an empty SMS. I've tried a lot with encoding and switch encoding but nothing works.

Can anybody tell me what's the difference between the call from PHP and the direct call from the console?

Comment: This happens because the user which who you are logged in is a different user as the user under which PHP runs (which is normally www-data). And I'm pretty sure that the PHP user (www-data) doesn't have the permission to run commands with sudo.

Comment: But if i'm not using any special characters the SMS is sent - only if there are special characters in there the SMS Message is cut exactly at this point e.g "This is a testmessage with äüpiöö" the Message is sent but the received Text is "This is a testmessage with " ... i gave www-data the permission to run commands.

Comment: Ahh sorry then I made a mistake...
It seems that you have a problem with the encoding.
You can try to set the correct system language in you PHP script via `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "de_DE.UTF-8");` (Btw. If you just give the sudo permission to your www-data user, revert it)

Comment: Thx for you reply - i tried it without success, i tried so many versions of encoding settings but nothing worked. interessting thing - when i output the string and the result from the database the following appears on the console:sudo gammu-smsd-inject TEXT +436802472618 -unicode -text öäüüüüü

[{"id":48,"tosend":"2019-06-26 18:00:00","smstext":"\u00f6\u00e4\u00fc\u00fc\u00fc\u00fc\u00fc",... 
if if put the smstext into the laravel log via Log::info again i works ... so strange to me ...

Comment: It seems that the text in your database is in a different encoding. What is the collation of your database/tables/columns?

Comment: The Database is utf8-bin, the table is utf8-bin and the column is also utf8-bin - i checked it just in case i was wrong. The interesting thing is that when returning the output from the DB to the console the output is like this smstext":"\u00f6\u00e4\u00fc\u00fc\u00fc\u00fc\u00fc - to the log or back to the calling method the encoding is fine ... i changed the collations in the db tough, is there anything else i could do?

Comment: addon: if i use this script     $unescaped_data = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u(\w{4})/', function ($matches) {
            return html_entity_decode('&#x' . $matches[1] . ';', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
        }, $smsmodel->smstext);
i get the correct output on the console but nothing changes when i try to send the string via gammu.

Comment: What says the gammu log ([documentation(https://wammu.eu/docs/manual/smsd/inject.html) param -l)?

Comment: Just had a look on GitHub, there gives a project which you can use...
https://github.com/uniquepurpose/smsphp/blob/master/sms.php
This guy use `shell_exec()` instead of `exec()` and also `escapeshellarg()`

Comment: you are a star, thx a lot ... the log unfortunatly doesn't say too much ... i'll try the shell_exec() - thx man!

Comment: Now things start the funny - i tried the shell_exec and the escapeshellarg() - it worked to some extent - i used this string "äääööö+++üüü" and i got only the "+++" - the rest was skipped ... i have the feeling that i will restrict the entry of special characteres instead of trying any longer which took almost a day or so .. thx Cody for the support!

Comment: did you also tried to use `-textutf8` instead of `-unicode`?

Comment: yes also with the option -textutf8 it's the same ... the data is read from the db correctly, i verified that by calling the service via browser, when the string is then sent via php something is happing there - maybe the user settings? i don't know - everything is fine everytime i execute the same string on the console tough!

Comment: Try out the answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51048762/gammu-sms-in-arabic-using-php-does-not-be-delivered/51078770#51078770